# Pie de foto al pasar por encima el raton

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Estoy intentando modificar una plantilla wordpress de "envato market" llamada Kalium, es un plantilla dedicada a mostrar contenido fotográfico, porfolios y galerías de varios tipos, uno de esos tipos es uno llamado "lightbox portfolio".

En las opciones del tema hay una opción para mostrar el nombre del porfolio (caption) cuando se muestra en modo lightbox (en este modo solo se muestra la imagen a pantalla completa y los controles para pasar de una imagen a otra) haciendo que aparezca en el pie de la imagen.

He buscado documentación por todos sitios para intentar hacer que ese pie de foto se muestre solo al pasar el ratón por encima, pero sinceramente no soy capaz de dar con el modo de hacerlo, por eso me gustaría preguntar si hay alguien que conozca la plantilla o alguien que me pueda dar alguna indicación para poder hacer esa modificación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de ver [este ejemplo](http://demo.kaliumtheme.com/photography/#carousel) y con el siguiente CSS deberia pasar lo que quieres.

```
.lg-hide-items > .lg-inner.lg-sub-html {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

El propio tema agrega y elimina la clase `.lg-hide-items` cuando pasas el mouse (y la elimina temporizda) así que aproveche el mecanismo para que todo se sincronize.

Avisa si tienes algún problema.

Comment: Voy a echarle un ojo, el tema tiene una opción para custom CSS a ver si consigo encajar el código sin meter la pata.

Muchas gracias por el consejo, a ver si me sale.

Comment: Pues no consigo hacer que el pie de foto del lightbox solo se muestre al pasar el raton por encima. He intentado tocarlo en el CSS principal y nada y en el Custom tampoco.

Comment: Raul, no pude comprobarlo y lo calcule en base a lo que pude ver son el inspector de css, intenta cambiarlo a `visibility: hidden !important`. si no anda, intenta poner un link a la pagina que estas haciendo asi puedo verlo en el caso contreto. Saludos.

Comment: hola @RaulPineda, como te fue? pudiste resolver el probelma?

Comment: Que va, les mande a los del soporte de Kalium un mensaje y que si quieres arroz catalina, he intentado cargar la sentencia que me comentaste desde el custom pero cuando hago la carga de la pagina se la pasa por el forro, así olímpicamente, y el problema es que es la pagina de un pintor importante de sevilla y su frase ha sido: "si hay algo encima de la imagen se contamina y desvirtúa la misma" asi que aqui estoy dando vueltas a ver como lo soluciono.

Muchas gracias por preocuparte, eres un crack.

Comment: Has resuelto el problema con soporte @RaulPineda

Answer (score 0):

Desactivando algunos parámetros de la plantilla quizás puedes instalar un plugin que haga de forma simple lo que quieres. Si entiendo bien tu pregunta este plugin de podría servir: https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-caption-hover/